# svn https: “ra_serf: An error occurred during SSL communication”

Tags: svn, ssl, tortoisesvn, uninstallation

I know this is the same title as other posts, but I have searched and searched and cannot find a solution.

I upgraded from TortoiseSVN 1.6 to 1.8.4 on all of my machines. My main dev machine started getting this error:

`ra_serf: An error occurred during SSL communication`

My client is using ProjectLocker.com, so I cannot check server logs.

From what I can tell from other posts on various sites, the issue is caused by a problem with either the network stack or SSL.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled tortoise about 5 times.

My only guess is: The first time I installed, it asked me to close all programs AND Windows Explorer. After the install it restarted Explorer. And all other installs, it does not shut down Explorer. Something got corrupted and subsequent installs of Tortoise do not replace the corrupted files.

I have reset the network stack as per: http://www.windows-secrets.co.uk/2013/08/repair-the-windows-87vista-tcpip-stack/

Any ideas how to completely remove Tortoise 1.8.4?
Any ideas what else I can try?

I cannot checkout the project I am working on and it's killin' me. I really do not want to reinstall windows on this machine. I'm sure that would fix it, but I don't want to go there.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's been so long I forgot about this thread.

I believe I just found a way to nuke the install and install a later version. It drove me nuts for about 2 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance that the issue is solved in the latest TortoiseSVN 1.8.x version which is built against newer [`serf` network library](https://code.google.com/p/serf/).

TortoiseSVN 1.8.7 is built against serf 1.3.5 and [there were related bugfixes in serf 1.3.4 and 1.3.5 versions](https://code.google.com/p/serf/source/browse/tags/1.3.5/CHANGES).

```
Serf 1.3.5 [2014-04-27, from /tags/1.3.5, rxxxx]
Fix issue #125: no reverse lookup during Negotiate authentication for proxies.
Fix a crash caused by incorrect reuse of the ssltunnel CONNECT request (r2316)
Cancel request if response parsing failed + authn callback set (r2319)
Update the expired certificates in the test suite.

Serf 1.3.4 [2014-02-08, from /tags/1.3.4, r2310]
Fix issue #119: Endless loop during ssl tunnel setup with Negotiate authn
Fix issue #123: Can't setup ssl tunnel which sends Connection close header
Fix a race condition when initializing OpenSSL from multiple threads (r2263)
Fix issue #138: Incorrect pkg-config file when GSSAPI isn't configured
```

Comment: still occurring in 1.8.11, Build 26392 x64 that uses serf 1.3.8

Comment: @JonB you can ask a new question describing how you reproduce this and providing other details.